# Update records using OLE DB Command Component SSIS

Tags: sql, etl, ssis

how to update the existing records using a OLEDB Command component as i have used look up transformation to split the existing records, but i need to update only the records/columns/cells which are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a merge statement in SQL which will enable you to write logic to check for column changes and only update the records that need it

Comment: Thanks Daryl, could you please elaborate this.

Comment: Within a Merge statement, you can choose to Update, Insert or Delete rows depending on whether columns already exist.  You can define which columns should be used to trigger an event so that you only update records that have changed.  Anoops link to an example below is a good place to start if you have not used Merge statements before.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not posed your specific scenario, here is a very good step-by-step elaboration:
    https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Let us know, if you need more help.